# Insert Django Wagtail Settings into Template

Tags: django, django-models, wagtail

I'm having what is surely to be user-error, a problem with populating my template with custom model that I've created and herited from BaseSetting. I can login to admin and can view the custom settings I've created; getting the data to show in my template is another thing.

Here is my BaseSetting

```
@register_setting
class SiteSettings(BaseSetting):
    ...
    company_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250, help_text='Enter your company name how you would like it to appear on the site')

    panels = [
        ...
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel('company_name'),
            ],
            heading="Company Info",
            classname="collapsible collapsed"
        ),
    ]
```

I've added `'wagtail.contrib.settings',` to my installed apps, add the context_processors per the [docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.2/reference/contrib/settings.html) and with my template settings set to

```
{% load wagtailsettings_tags %}
{% get_settings %}
{{ settings.app_label.SiteSettings.company_name }}
```

I still get nothing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that your app is named ``app_label`` ? This needs to be replaced with the actual name of your application as per http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.5.2/reference/contrib/settings.html#using-in-django-templates

Comment: This is what happens when you have too many things going on...thank you for pointing out the obvious - man do I feel foolish :)  Can you set your response as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Ok, no problem :-)

Comment: There are more update docs about Wagtail Settings here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/reference/contrib/settings.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `app_label` in `{{ settings.app_label.SiteSettings.company_name }}` with the actual name of your application as per http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.5.2/reference/contrib/settings.html#using-in-django-templates.